# How to handle Bootstrap-Vue Select easily?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

```
<b-form-select
   v-model="form.depart"
   :options="department"
   class="depart"
   required
></b-form-select>
```

My coming array of object is:

```
[
   { id: 1, department_name: 'CSE', department_email: 'cse@example.com'},
   { id: 2, department_name: 'EEE', department_email: 'eee@example.com'},
]
```

This data is not loading in the Select Option. I want just `department_name` in the select option. Given NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please specify your text-field and value field if these are not `value` and `text` in the array of objects. Check with the below code

```
<b-form-select
   v-model="form.depart"
   :options="department"
   class="depart"
   required
   value-field="department_name"
   text-field="department_name"
></b-form-select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you help me for another query? I want to add `Select Department` in the department array. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Input field**

```
  <b-form-select
    v-model="depart"
    :options="department"
    class="depart"
    required
    value-field="department_name"
    text-field="department_name"
  ></b-form-select>
```

**To add the "Select department" option add the following:**

```
data() {
  return {
    depart: 'Select department',
    department: [{
        id: 0,
        department_name: 'Select department',
        disabled: true
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        department_name: 'CSE',
        department_email: 'cse@example.com'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        department_name: 'EEE',
        department_email: 'eee@example.com'
      },
    ]

  }
}
```

**Here is a working version**
https://jsfiddle.net/g3kLqscy/

Comment: There is no difference with the previous answer. Thank you.

Comment: You asked how to add this to your array